# Largest triangle from set of points not containing any other point

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

Consider a set of points. Given the (integer) x and y coordinates of each point, what is an efficient (faster than `O(n^4)` brute force) method to find the triangle with the largest area that does not contain any other point?

This is an excerpt from an old set of ACM-ICPC practice problems.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249392/finding-all-empty-triangles

Comment: Thanks. That link helped a lot.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation
This triangulation of points has the property that no point is located within another's triangle and satisfies one of your constraints. This does not necessarily mean that the largest triangle will be produced. However, if you use an incremental method of to construct this triangulation you could try modify it to maximise the size of your triangles.