# Count empty triangles in planar graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a set of n points in a plane, I am looking for an algorithm that will generate all empty triangles. Empty triangle is defined as a triangle that has 3 of the given points at its vertices and none of the given points in the interior. I could compute take all combinations of three points (n choose 3) and then eliminate those which are not empty but I am looking for a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0020019081900417 Related?

Comment: We have all the vertices of a graph but no edges. We need to construct the edges to form the triangles. The clique problem would not apply without knowing the edges.

Comment: @MBo: the question is not about a triangulation. It is about the number of empty triangles, which is well defined.

Comment: @Yves Daoust OK, you are right

Comment: In the worst case, there can be O(N³) triangles (all empty). Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31249392/1196549

Comment: This is called a Delaunay triangulation.  Several algorithms are described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation

Comment: you want to know only the number to the question, or the exact `O(N^3)` triangles?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Right, it is a problem in computational geometry. The ask is for the algorithm that generates all the empty triangles in the smallest runtime as possible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I looked at the answer to the other stackoverflow question and it contained a link to "Searching for empty Convex polygons" by Dobkin, David P. / Edelsbrunner, Herbert / Overmars, Mark H."  I think that is the answer I am looking for. If not, it is a good start.

Comment: @ravenspoint I do not see how to use Delauney triangulation to generate all the empty triangles. Can you elaborate.

Comment: @shole I want an algorithm to generate all the empty triangles. I would like it to be as efficient as possible.